How does browser is directed to new URL when last respone's code is 200 instead of 301
We are using Auth0's OpenID connect by ASP.NET OWIN component. In Chrome Devtool, there is one request I don't understand how it happens.
The first request is to https://iguide-login.us.auth0.com/authorize/resume. Its response is 200 and there is no content in response. Besides,this request type is document, not ajax.
Who initialize the next request to /callback/? If the first response code is 301, then I can understand. But why 200 can also lead to redirect?
Here is the details.
First request detail.

First request's response content is empty.

First request type is document.


oh boy, aspx pages, fun! An HTTP 200 response will cannot initiate a redirect (by itself). I think what you're looking for is information regarding the call back and the redirect_uri.  You can find more information here: https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/redirect-users-after-login

It is a very old legcy project. Actually what I am investigating is from technique perspective. You see, it is response status 200, then why browser is starting request to /callback? I even suspect that there are some javascript code like window.locatio.href=xxx inside response of /resume. But the response content is empty! How does that happen?

I recommend just checking out an article or two on the subject. They would be able to explain it more wholistically than answering this single piece of the puzzle.  https://samwalpole.com/web-app-authentication-using-auth0-aspnet-core-and-nuxtjs#heading-basic-authentication-flow

Thanks @AdamVincent. Most articles are describle the whole general flow. Acutally I am stuck at this very specific http request and response quesiton. How browser initialize request to /callback after a 200 response?  Maybe we can fogeot the Auth0 thing and narrow down to this specific question. Is there anyway to achieve this redirect with response 200?

I finally found the root cause. Just to share with who may also have same doubt.
Previously, I thought /resume... does not return any html content becasue Chrome devtool is saying

Failed to load response:No resource with given identifier found.

It is wrong. I finally found that /resume... did return html content. I got it using Fiddler. Chrome devtool has its own bug or debat for this Failed to load response for years.
When we are seeing this error, we should not think the server does not return any response content. We should think Chrome failed to load the content due to some reason. We can use Fiddler to get the actual response content if wanted.
Here is the full response content of /resume, it clearly shows why browser does the redirect.
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Submit This Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>

  <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form method="post" action="https://xxx/callback/">xxx</form>
  </body>

</html>

